# Issue with Generate table fetch SQL SERVER 2016

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm try to pull the data from SQL Server and using the generate table fetch. When I use MYSQL database instead SQL Server for the same generate table fetch it's working as expected. Whenever I use to connect SQL Server I'm getting error as below.

```
GenerateTableFetch[id=07bed292-0162-1000-0000-00004bc12345] failed to process session due to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Order by clause cannot be null or empty when using row paging: Order by clause cannot be null or empty when using row paging
```

SQL Server Version: 2016

I gone through the below link and came to know that there is a bug for generate table fetch for SQL Server. However I'm not whether the bug is fixed or not.

https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/1510

Nifi Version I'm using - 1.5

Could someone please let me know whether the bug is fixed or not, If not any work around solution for this bug.

Here is my flow.

[image]

**Edit:**

GenerateTableFetc:
[image]

Comment: The pull request you linked to was merged and released in Apache NiFi 1.2.0, so it is definitely contained in the code you are using for NiFi 1.5.0. Can you share the configuration for the `GenerateTableFetch` processor? You need to have the *Database Type* set to `MS SQL 2012+`.

Comment: @Andy, Updated the question and attached the generatetablefetch configuration screenshot and getting the below error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in some of the DatabaseAdapters in NiFi, using GenerateTableFetch with no Max-value Column set. In this case there's a workaround, you can use the 2008 driver, then a ReplaceText processor to replace "ORDER BY asc" with "ORDER BY newid() asc". I'm trying to find out everywhere this could be an issue, I'll write up a Jira to cover all the cases. The general symptom is OFFSET/LIMIT clauses without an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Hi @mattyb,  replace text is working as expected if it is single table as we are hard coding the primary key in replacement text. Do we have any work around if we are trying to pull multiple tables (Don't want to hard the primary key in replacement text) based on the table name we need to pull the primary key dynamically from intermediate table we we are maintaining the table names and primary keys

Comment: If you put the intermediate table / primary key entries in a file, you can use LookupAttribute to get the primary key from the table name, then use Expression Language in ReplaceText to inject the primary key

Comment: @mattyb Can you please share the sample regex.